Whitehead product of null homotopic maps
Let $X$ be a CW-complex and let $f, g: S^n \to X$, $n\geq 2$ be continuous maps that are null homotopic.
I would like to inquire:

Does it follow that the Whitehead product $[f, g]: S^{2n-1} \to X$ is also null homotopic?
If this is indeed the case, could you please provide a proof or justification for your answer?

I look forward to your thoughtful response!

The Whitehead product is defined as a bilinear operation on homotopy groups, so if $f_0$ and $f_1$ represent the same element $[f_0] = [f_1]$ in $\pi_n(X)$, then the Whitehead products $[[f_0], \alpha]$ and $[[f_1], \alpha]$ will be the same. If $f_0$ is the constant map, then the corresponding element in $\pi_n(X)$ is the zero element, so by bilinearity, $[[f_0], \alpha] = [0, \alpha] = 0$. (For example, $[0, \alpha] = [0 + 0, \alpha] = [0, \alpha] + [0, \alpha]$.)
